# Sum Matlab from 0 to 10000 on function

Tags: matlab

syms k

S1 = symsum(1/((2*k)+1)^2,k,0,1000)

The result is this

> 59039372973827482202940226722672826425297321906316082356858983822169051832268260251807527611479190413293513875429587706186073872918905490907386679472102966658686481651660967093301512141946288248492833396616338323741632085379508599235923841007033467883638349122388806376761808189104503262045883240287482992169819848342303098664924237976221795758421152603069387903705445513260596627332283139648508194960733619500093010571517561429904500013876585156927070119332440687162376758374919870699278800835146651318465663183182583101377584105366558079836223068786457324044080570317649838092783113721959819118571747662368360095513856052974454509201490370810246175872510881504730747209788019551000695511879992198550955686739483474761130248789609061549535677663474218135370195381615899214931316241080337028498241295985409686314819267606796712968280842464845294917738460317179001491697993067157425958639996885239616893392960282441289069600101430806922004624472226999315951355963789249300352610312601262349650287009275097201871774652260892220551489305368617001974326978428202443548923140478853569492070442010110016068635424791389124439271253578545895132216218268847919848655110002938693346760862649668457282775860633067627110099340660770861888592018701206483696615682617062811616008107086256694453990688805738127607846586853460003073465075155412119309273843527076321601670400373937698518621100907936577387919537592519265365346619712200304996044229704602647674114176291753575322917531444831938509001759491229575945273985556769609288625450013634760596805884195325794441020339210402987018058377081579351119704065092777310976461961832919116412535470810011337916688085616171422473409544885864650134157327448050685723673514545806331081542320899927

It is a number in this form a/b

Why is this happening??

Do you know how to do this in octave too?

Comment: Have you checked description in [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html)?

Comment: Why do you use symbolic math for a numerical problem?

Comment: Don't use `syms`

Answer (score 2):

```
k = (0:1000);
k_sum = sum(1./((2*k)+1).^2);
disp(k_sum)
```

It's interesting that you jumped straight to using `syms` when the basic matlab functions work perfectly well for this problem. Why is that?